# SSRS Report- Using two data sets

Tags: sql

I want to do a calculation using two different datasets, but I cant seem to do it in the expression field. Any ideas on how I can add, multiply or divide using the two datasets? In the Fields, I added a new one and trying to set the expression only gives me DataSet1, but I want to add a  DataSet2 field and a DataSet1 field.

Thanks guys

Comment: Are you doing this in a grid? Textbox? Where are you trying to do this? What is the general layout of the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly use two data sets in there.

Imho you should move your data to db queries, then add a query that does your job, include this in your report then.

Alternative you can calculate some aggregat in a field, hide the field, do this with more/many as you want, then use your operatores on the result fields.